# Returning two 2 json objects from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I have a small feedback form with two inputs. I want the error message to append to one another in the same div using JQuery. The error message works fine if there is only one error message, but when I return two json objects, both messages will not display at the same time. Is it possible to return 2 associative arrays with the same key to JQuery? How do I append the error messages to the same div? Everything works fine except how the error messages are displayed.

Note: This program is a JQuery Mobile Application

PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
    $errors = array();

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($email)) {
                 //Do something
    } else {
        $errors = "Invalid email.";
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "{$errors}"));

    }

    if (!empty($feedback)) {
                //Do something
    } else {
        $errors = "Feeback field can not be empty.";
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "{$errors}"));
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        //Database Insertion here
        echo json_encode(array("success" => "Feedback submission successful."));
    }
}
```

JQuery Code

```
$(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bind('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('includes/form.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            if (data.error) {

                $('.error').slideDown(100).html(data.error);

            } else {
                $('.error').hide();
                $('.success').slideDown(100).html(data.success);
            }

        }, "json");
    });
});
```

HTML Form Code

```
         <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" id="contact_form" data-ajax="false">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">

            <label for="feedback">Feedback:</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="feedback" id="feedback" placeholder="Feedback"></textarea>              
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback" class="submit">

        </form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I feel so silly. I forgot to append the error messages in the php script haha. Thank you to all who answered.

Comment: JSON is required to represent 1 object, certainly you could come up with a way to have your two error messages in one object.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. I will put my messages into one object then. I just wanted to see if it was possible to return more than one object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all the errors before you echo your output which is in json format

E.g

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = $_POST['email'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
$errors = "";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($email)) {
             //Do something
} else {
    $errors .= "Invalid email.<br/>";


}

if (!empty($feedback)) {
            //Do something
} else {
    $errors .= "Feeback field can not be empty.<br/>";
}

if ($errors != "") {
    echo json_encode(array("success" => "Feedback submission successful."));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("error" => $errors));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have 1 key map to 2 values.

Comment: Could you maybe steer me in the right direction on how to get the messages to append to each other in JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a simpler, one-dimensional array structure to store the error messages:

```
$errors[0] = 'error message one';
$errors[1] = 'error message two';
```

Output them from the server:

```
echo json_encode($errors);
```

Then use `jQuery.each()` to iterate over the array after getting your POST response:

```
$.each(error, function() {
    // do something with each error
});
```